Unable to retrieve a dependency using database view
Im trying to use data base view to join fetch any dependency that is associated with the Employee class which extends Person.
I have a search method where I'd like to search by the number of job positions associated with the employee.
After creating an Employee & assigning a jobPosition Im trying to use the search method to find the Employee by the number of job positions but I get the following error:
RROR 14956 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement [Kolumna "P.ID" nie istnieje
Column "P.ID" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name, p.surname AS surname, p.job_position_count AS numberOfJobPositions FROM person_view p WHERE p.type = 'employee' [42122-214]] [SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name, p.surname AS surname, p.job_position_count AS numberOfJobPositions FROM person_view p WHERE p.type = 'employee']; SQL [SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name, p.surname AS surname, p.job_position_count AS numberOfJobPositions FROM person_view p WHERE p.type = 'employee']] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "P.ID" doesn't exist
Column "P.ID" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name, p.surname AS surname, p.job_position_count AS numberOfJobPositions FROM person_view p WHERE p.type = 'employee'

Here is my code
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends Person {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<JobPosition> jobPositions;

@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String pesel;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private String emailAddress;
    @Version
    private int version;
}

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person
(
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    surname VARCHAR(255),
    pesel VARCHAR(20),
    height DOUBLE,
    weight DOUBLE,
    email_address VARCHAR(255),
    type VARCHAR(50), -- Type differentiates between Employee, Student, Pensioner, etc.
    version INT
    );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS job_position
(
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    position_name VARCHAR(255),
    start_date DATE,
    end_date DATE,
    salary DOUBLE,
    employee_id BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id)
    );
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW person_view AS
SELECT
    p.id AS person_id,
    p.name,
    p.surname,
    p.pesel,
    p.height,
    p.weight,
    p.email_address,
    p.type,
    jp.position_name,
    jp.start_date,
    jp.end_date,
    jp.salary,
    COUNT(jp.id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.id) AS job_position_count
FROM person p
         LEFT JOIN job_position jp ON p.id = jp.employee_id
WHERE p.type = 'employee'
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.surname, p.pesel, p.height, p.weight, p.email_address, p.type,
         jp.position_name, jp.start_date, jp.end_date, jp.salary
HAVING COUNT(jp.id) > 0;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file_import
(
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP(6),
    file_path VARCHAR(255),
    finished_at TIMESTAMP(6),
    last_processed_row BIGINT,
    started_at TIMESTAMP(6),
    status VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT file_import_status_check CHECK (status IN ('PENDING', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED', 'IN_PROGRESS'))
    );

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {
    Optional<Person> findById(Long id);

    @Query("select e from Employee e left join fetch e.jobPositions where e.id=:id")
    Optional<Employee> findByIdWithJobs(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name, p.surname AS surname, p.job_position_count AS numberOfJobPositions FROM person_view p WHERE p.type = 'employee'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmployeeDto> findAllEmployeesWithJobPositions();
}

@Component
public class JobPositionsSpecificationProvider implements SpecificationProvider {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;

    public JobPositionsSpecificationProvider(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(SearchCriteria criteria) {
         return "numberOfJobPositions".equals(criteria.getKey()) && "range".equals(criteria.getOperation());
    }

    @Override
    public Specification<Person> getSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {

            List<EmployeeDto> employees = personRepository.findAllEmployeesWithJobPositions();

            Integer minJobPositions = parseInteger(criteria.getValue());
            Integer maxJobPositions = parseInteger(criteria.getSecondValue());

            return buildJobPositionPredicate(minJobPositions, maxJobPositions, root, criteriaBuilder);
        };
    }

    private Predicate buildJobPositionPredicate(Integer minJobPositions, Integer maxJobPositions, Root<Person> root, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        Expression<Integer> jobPositionCount = root.get("numberOfJobPositions");

        if (minJobPositions != null && maxJobPositions != null) {
            return criteriaBuilder.between(jobPositionCount, minJobPositions, maxJobPositions);
        } else if (minJobPositions != null) {
            return criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(jobPositionCount, minJobPositions);
        } else if (maxJobPositions != null) {
            return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(jobPositionCount, maxJobPositions);
        }

        return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
    }

    private Integer parseInteger(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt((String) value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            return (Integer) value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<PersonDto> searchPersons(String searchCriteriaParam, Pageable pageable) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<SearchCriteria> searchCriteria = objectMapper.readValue(searchCriteriaParam, new TypeReference<List<SearchCriteria>>() {
        });

        Specification<Person> specification = PersonSpecification.any();
        for (SearchCriteria criteria : searchCriteria) {
            specification = personSpecification.addSpecification(specification, criteria);
        }

        Page<Person> result = personRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
        return result.map(personMapper::toDto);
    }

I'd need to edit it so it will allow me to use the database view (as there are various types of people such as student employee pensioner) & retrieve the job positions when using the search method so I can look for employees between 0 & 2 job positions, for example.

What is the SQL generated by your JPA provider when you do a simple findById for an employee instance? Use (and show) that as a comparison with your native SQL. For your latest error - numberOfJobPositions doesn't exist in your model given in the question, so where is/was the p.job_position_count column in your view query coming from exactly? It doesn't make sense to start fetching columns  in a view that you don't use in the existing Employee/Person model unless you are going to create an entirely new entity to map it - and if so, make sure those fields have data.

The error is in the query that is the annotation of findAllEmployeesWithJobPositions method:
SELECT p.id AS id,
  p.name AS name, 
  p.surname AS surname, 
  p.job_position_count AS number_of_job_positions 
FROM person_view p 
WHERE p.type = 'employee'

Because the person_view does not have an id field but a person_id. The correct query is the following:
SELECT p.person_id AS id,
  p.name AS name, 
  p.surname AS surname, 
  p.job_position_count AS number_of_job_positions 
FROM person_view p 
WHERE p.type = 'employee'

This may solve the first sql error.
However, you have also to map also the numberOfJobPositions field in the Employee class (what is the EmployeeDto?), and create a separate EmployeeRepository where you have to move the findByIdWithJobs and findAllEmployeesWithJobPositions methods to make that entity be managed correctly by Spring Data.
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends Person {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<JobPosition> jobPositions;

    private Long numberOfJobPositions;
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

    @Query("select e from Employee e left join fetch e.jobPositions where e.id=:id")
    Optional<Employee> findByIdWithJobs(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT p.id AS person_id, p.name AS name, p.surname AS surname, p.job_position_count AS number_of_job_positions FROM person_view p WHERE p.type = 'employee'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Employee> findAllEmployeesWithJobPositions();

}


I have updated it to the above proposed code in PersonRepository although after changing it I get the following error:
2024-09-10T14:27:55.659+02:00  WARN 56679 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Could not resolve attribute 'numberOfJobPositions' of 'com.example.personmanagement.model.person.Person']


@MariuszNowicki I updated the answer, have you tried adding the missing fields?
